# Port forwarding through dd wrt

Tags: router, port-forwarding, dd-wrt

I'm trying to do port forwarding to one of my local computers and I'm having some trouble with it. The forwarding from router 1 (R1) already works, but I can't get it to work on R2, at least not as it should.

I would like to forward port 8000 to 192.168.1.126.
Here's a sketch of the network I'm on.

[image]

And here's the setup of R2

[image]

The interesting thing is, opening http://10.0.0.3:8000 from the machine having 192.168.1.5 works, which tells me that the port forwarding setup should actually be ok. But trying to get to http://10.0.0.3:8000 from one of the 10.0.0.x machines just always fails.

Getting to the Router webinterface from 10.0.0.x works.

Does anyone have some good advice on that?

Here are some more infos about the dd wrt version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using two routers together, with what in your case may have dhcp/firewalls running on both, will always be problematic. The solution would be to setup the ddwrt as an access point, with the other router giving out the 192.168.x.x via it's dhcp. Port forward from the other router and problem almost solved, apart from the 10.0.0.x dhcp server which I assume is on R1? Most ordinary routers only have one dhcp on them - Please confirm what the other router is.

If you wish to go another route then on the main router put the address of the ddwrt router in the DMZ then it won't have difficulties in port forwarding.